# Caching issue with Hibernate EhCache

Tags: multithreading, hibernate, ehcache

Our project is using Hibernate 3.0 for DB access. We are using 2nd level cache and query cache to cache the queries and entities.EhCache is used for caching purpose.

The DAO method getData() fetches data and initializes all the associations using Hibernate.initialize() before session is closed.

The main execution thread triggers asynchronous executer tasks to generate data for various modules. These tasks in turn call the above method to get the data.
After the first db call, the query, entity and it’s associations are cached so that they can be fetched from cache rather than DB for subsequent calls. The main thread then
accesses the same data after these tasks complete for additional work.

Everything works fine on LOCAL environment but the code fails in DEV/INT env.

In dev,the call to the above DAO method fails in main thread. The initialization of one of the associations is failing. The Hibernate.initialize() method call returns null even though data is there.
The same call works fine for the asynch tasks but only fails in main thread. In logs I don’t see any statements related to cache hit/miss but for tasks I am able to see them

What can be the possible issues ?

Comment: The only thing you say about your code and the problem you face is that `Hibernate.initialize()` returns null. That's a bit short. Especially considering that `Hibernate.initialize()` can't return null, since it returns `void`.

Comment: ohhh srry...my mistake.......when I check that collection value it's null..I don't think there is any problem with initialize() method....I don't see any cache logs after getData() method